# Selenium на веб-сервере с профилем Firefox

Tags: python, сервер, selenium, firefox

Пытаюсь написать скрипт, который синхронизирует мои данные с одного сайта на другой. У первого сайта нет публичного api, но у меня есть ссылки, которые дадут мне response со всеми данными в формате json. Главная проблема - чтобы получить эти данные, я должен быть авторизован, поэтому я решил использовать selenium. Авторизоваться с его помощью сложновато - recaptcha2, но я сделал новый профиль в Firefox, авторизовался на сайте и использую этот профиль в скрипте. Я так же хочу запускать скрипт на своем удаленном сервере без GUI, поэтому использую pyvirtualdisplay.

Получилось как-то так:

```py
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

display = Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600))
display.start()

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/admin/.cache/mozilla/firefox/o0eaxyux.user')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
browser.get("https://example.com/p/api/v5/profile/blabla")
response = json.loads(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
print(response)

browser.quit()
display.stop()
```

And it works perfectly on my pc. On the server, pyvirtualdisplay also works if i don't use the profile. But if I use the profile on the server, I get the error:
И на локальном пк это работает отлично. Но на сервере это работает только если я **не** указываю профиль Firefox ( `browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'./geckodriver'`). Но тогда я не авторизован. А если профиль подключить, тогда будет ошибка:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "1.py", line 7, in <module>
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/firefox/webdriver.py", line 174, in __init__
    keep_alive=True)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 157, in __init__
    self.start_session(capabilities, browser_profile)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 252, in start_session
    response = self.execute(Command.NEW_SESSION, parameters)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/webdriver.py", line 321, in execute
    self.error_handler.check_response(response)
  File "/home/admin/.local/lib/python3.6/site-packages/selenium/webdriver/remote/errorhandler.py", line 242, in check_response
    raise exception_class(message, screen, stacktrace)
selenium.common.exceptions.TimeoutException: Message: connection refused
```

geckodriver.log показывает только одну строчку:

```
1575543823086   mozrunner::runner   INFO    Running command: "/usr/bin/firefox" "-marionette" "-foreground" "-no-remote" "-profile" "/tmp/rust_mozprofilegsEa0V"
```

**UPD.**
Проблема точно в том, что я скопировал профиль с локального пк на сервер и он не является "родным" браузеру. С третьего пк тоже сделал профиль, скопировал на локальный пк, где у меня всё работало и с профилем от третьего пк - та же ошибка.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Для запуска вебдрайвера вам обязательно нужно указывать путь до geckodriver, так как этот драйвер обеспечивает взаимодействие пайтон приложения с браузером по апи удаленного управления. А для указания профиля требуется использовать класс FirefoxProfile()

```
from selenium import webdriver

profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('path/to/profile/dir')
browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path='path/to/gecko', firefox_profile=profile)
```

Для авторизации вам, скорее всего, нужны только куки сессии. Скорее всего задачу можно решить через requests, выдернув куки из запроса браузера и передав их в запрос.

```
import requests

headers = {
    "User-Agent": "user agent from browser",
    "Cookie": "cookie from request",
}

r = requests.get("url/to/json", headers=headers, timeout=(5,15))
print(r.json())
```

Еще рекомендую обеспечить закрытие виртуального дисплея. Кажется, pyvirtualdisplay имеет возможность запуска как менеджера контекста. Попробуйте сделать так

```
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display

with Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600)):
    # some code
```

Comment: Путь указан, драйвер находится в директории со скриптом. Указывание профиля через firefox_profile= разницы не даст, т.к. первым аргументом он профиль как раз и принимает. 
Иначе бы у меня вообще ничего не работало на локальном пк, а на сервере не работало бы без профиля.
Проблему нашел: дело в том, что профиль был скопирован с локального пк на сервер. Именно это ему не нравится.

Comment: Профиль я как раз для куки и использовал. Нашел еще способ решить данный вопрос, сейчас добавлю в ответы. За подсказку с pyvirtualdisplay - спасибо

Comment: Сори. Не внимательно прочитал код. Попробуйте все таки куки дернуть и реквестом отправить запрос

Comment: Оо, я думал что невозможно сделать это через requests. А оказывается, всё так просто. Так намного лучше. И быстрее :) Спасибо

Answer (score 0):

Как обойти то, что профиль не "родной" - не знаю, но обойти можно сохранением cookies из сессии и последующем их использовании:

- Сохраняем cookies (на пк с рабочим профилем)

```py
import pickle
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

with Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600)):
    profile = webdriver.FirefoxProfile('/home/admin/.cache/mozilla/firefox/o0eaxyux.user')
    browser = webdriver.Firefox(profile, executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
    browser.get("https://example.com/p/api/v5/profile/blabla")
    pickle.dump(browser.get_cookies() , open("cookies.pkl","wb"))
    browser.quit()
```

- Используем

```py
import pickle
from pyvirtualdisplay import Display
from selenium import webdriver

with Display(visible=0, size=(800, 600)):

    browser = webdriver.Firefox(executable_path=r'./geckodriver')
    browser.get("https://example.com/p/api/v5/profile/blabla")
    cookies = pickle.load(open("cookies.pkl", "rb"))
    for cookie in cookies:
        browser.add_cookie(cookie)
    browser.get("https://example.com/p/api/v5/profile/blabla")
    response = json.loads(browser.find_element_by_tag_name('body').text)
    print(response)
    browser.quit()
```